# como enviar una variable al database de codeigniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Necesito que el database de codeigniter me revisa unas variables para hacer dinámica la conexión a la base de datos dependiendo de la que el cliente requiera usar, la idea es enviar los parámetros de configuración mediante una variable.

```
$db['db3'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'tecmmas',
    'database' => $database,   -------->seria algo así 
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

los datos ya los tengo en un controlador pero no se como enviarlos al database.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar la base de datos  `$this->db->db_select($db);`

revisa el manual de usuario de [codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=db_select#CI_DB_driver::db_select)